# Disabling button with Jquery Or Javascript When some other button was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

i have these two buttons and i want one of them to be disabled when the other was clicked.

There  is html

```
    <button type="submit" id="button_user" name="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#fsearch">Pretraga terena na sajtu</button>
  <button type="submit" id="button_field" name="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#usearch">Pretraga korisnika na sajtu</button>
```

I have managed to do this with two functions and onclick, but i would like to know is there any elegant way to do this in one function so that inline js can be avoided?

this is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


disable_one = function(){
    if($('button_user').data('clicked', true)){
        $('#button_field').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        return;
    }
};
disable_two = function(){
    if($('button_field').data('clicked', true)){
        $('#button_user').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        return;
    }
};


});
```

Comment: If you don't absolutely need buttons, use radio elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$('.btn.btn-small.btn-primary').click(function () {
    $('.btn.btn-small.btn-primary').not($(this)).prop('disabled', true)
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2BgdD/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#button_user').on('click', function() {
    $('#button_field').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/BPZT7/

Answer (score 0):

Bind a Jquery click event to the button class and then us the target property with the Jquery is method (http://api.jquery.com/is/).

```
 $("your button class").click(function(e) {
    if($(e.target).is("#button_user")) {
        //Disable button_field
    } else {
        // Disable button_user
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i managed to do this very simple and clear. Now, if the visitor change his mind this button is enabled so that he can choose again.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

$('#button_user').click(function () {
    if (button_field.disabled==false){
        button_field.disabled = true;
    }
    else {
    button_field.disabled = false ;
    } 
});
$('#button_field').click(function () {
    if (button_user.disabled==false){
        button_user.disabled = true;
    }
    else {
    button_user.disabled = false ;
    } 
});


});
```